# "ignore background" in matlab segmentation

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have an image shot with an x-ray for which I want to test different segmentation algorithm (like the ones found at http://www.academia.edu/913222/segmentation_techniques)

How can I ignore the background in the calculation, i.e. how can I ignore anything that has a gray value of under 50,000 (for a 16 bit image)?

the code I'm using right now is:

```
clc;
clear;
[fn,pn]=uigetfile({'*.TIF','Image files'}, 'Select an image');
x = imread(fullfile(pn,fn));
T=graythresh(x);
y=im2bw(x,T);
imshow(y);
```

but I also want to test different segmentation techniques.

I am trying to model the future implementation of a software in order to find the best course of action and this software will ignore the "background" (I already have a succesful implementation of the otsu algorithm.

Thanks for your wisdom =).

Comment: @beaker T is found and set from computing the otsu threshold - I'm not sure I can give it a set range

Comment: Otsu's method is simply one particular way to choose a threshold level. If you already know the threshold level you're interested in there's no point in having another algorithm calculate it for you. Do you want to use 50,000 as your threshold (or whatever other number you choose) or do you want the threshold to be automatically calculated and Otsu just isn't giving you what you want?

Comment: @beaker As it is now, Otsu is taking the black background into account in order to calculate the optimal threshold. I would like it not to, and calculate the optimal threshold without taking the black background into account - My image is an x-ray of a rat and I want to see which type of segmentation separates the bone from the soft tissue, not the outline of the rat from the background

Comment: What I'm saying is that you can manually set the threshold level to anything you like (between 0 and 1) based on inspecting the values in the original image, or in the histogram, or simply playing around until you get the desired results. If you want the threshold calculated for you automatically, a locally adaptive technique as in your link will give you at least slightly better results.

Comment: right - what I'm doing right now is comparing the accuracy of different algorithms before I do my own implementation in c#.
For example, I've already implemented Otsu in c# and made it ignore all the values under 50,000 (I didn't include them in the histogram). The program I'm writing needs to calculate that threshold automatically, so I'm trying to model the behavior if the future software in order to find the best implementation which requires me to "ignore" the values under 50,000 when computing the thresholds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use Otsu only on the pixel values above 50000, you can simply write

```
T = graythresh(x(x>50000));
```

Comment: thanks a lot! that's exactly what I was looking for. I guess my matlab got a bit rusty...